# jQuery append after select

Tags: jquery, select, append

I'm appending some html elements with jquery:

```
$('#Table').append("<div id='newDiv'>bla bla bla </div>");
```

I want select this item but 
`$("#newDiv")` dosen't work.

How can I select that new element using ID?

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes are messed up:

```
$('#Table').append("<div id='newDiv'>bla bla bla </div>");
```

then there is no reason doing a $("#newDiv") won't work AFTER this append has happened.

Answer (score 0):

in your case, you should be able to call what you want by doing this:

```
$("#Table").on('click', "div#newDiv",function(){//your custom codes})
```

hope it works

Answer (score 0):

Well, supposing that your #table is indeed a table element, you should not place a DIv between table and tr/thead/tbody elements, your append must be a table inner element for instance:

```
$('#Table').append('<tr><td><div id="newDiv">bla bla bla </div></td></tr>');
```

That should work and you will be enable to select your ID.